# How safe is 'is_numeric' against sql injection

Tags: php, sql, security, oracle10g, sql-injection

I use is_numeric for everything, the only input I get from users is a form with an Student ID number....

I recently was reading up on SQL Injections and was wondering if the following precaution is necessary?

**Currently I have:**

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['sid']){
     $sid = $_POST['sid']; 
     $query = "select * from student where sid='".$sid."'";
     // More Code...
}
```

**What I've read is safer**

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['sid']){
     $sid = (int) $_POST['sid'];
     $query = "select * from student where sid='".$sid."'";
     // More Code...
}
```

**Is one version really safer than the other? How would someone bypass 'is_numeric'?**

Also, would this be any less safe than what I currently have?

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['sid']){
     $query = "select * from student where sid='".$_POST['sid']."'";
     // More Code...
}
```

**So, I guess what I am really asking, is if one of these code blocks is *truly* safer than another one**

---

EDIT: Sorry I didn't state this early but I am using oracle 10g database, not mysql. With oci_connect();

Comment: Do you understand the *meaning* of these code blocks?

Comment: Neither is really safer than the other, however you would be better off using bound parameters.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I believe I do, I think they are all theoretically equally the same... but assuming can lead to problems, that's why I want to check with others

Comment: @Pitchinnate What do you mean by bound parameters?

Comment: Either you understand or ask this question. Yet understanding is always better than simple "yes" or "no".

Comment: *The only consistent and reliable way to mitigate SQL injection is to use placeholders.* Keep it simple - for yourself and future maintainers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1

Comment: I am using an oracle database, connecting with oci_connect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you going through these questions asking about how you can sanitize your inputs so that you can build SQL statements from outside data?  **Building SQL statements from outside data is dangerous.**

Rather than wasting your time worrying about how you can come up with another halfway thought out "solution", stop and put on your Big Programmer Pants and start using prepared statements and bound variables.

Here is a fantastic answer that will get you started: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

You can also check http://bobby-tables.com/php for other examples.

Looks to me like you can still do prepared statements and bound variables with Oracle: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php or through PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: "Big Programmer Pants" >_<

Comment: I am not using a mysql database, I am using and oracle database 10g using oci_connect.

Comment: @Arian: Looks to me like you can still do prepared statements and bound variables with Oracle: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php or through PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @AndyLester Can you add that into your answer... So I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Any database driver implementation worth its salt has support for bound variables and prepared statements. If you're using a driver implementation that doesn't, then get rid of it. Immediately.

Comment: What is a wearer of big programming pants to do when they need to be able to programmatically modify parts of the statement depending on how variables are set, which seems to preclude the use of prepared statements. For example, if the $_POST['gender'] variable isset then I want to add it to my where clause, if it isn't set I want to leave it off of the where clause entirely.

Comment: Then modify the SQL to add part of the WHERE clause, using a placeholder of course, and also add $_POST['gender'] to your bind variables array.

Comment: This is all good information and I agree with the sentiment but it is _not_ an answer to the actual question. There may be many good reasons to need to know the answer, including working in legacy code where restructuring for a prepared statement is too big a change.

Answer (score 8):

As a rule of thumb, it is not safe enough to just *check* the data, you should always *preprocess* the data before using it.

Let’s say you don’t know *all* the internals of how the `is_numeric` works. Or you don’t know if its logic or its implementation will change in future. Or you did not test it heavily enough. Or its documentation lacks some very specific but important note.

All in all, one day it just *might* happen that `is_numeric` returned `TRUE` but the data is not safe to be used in SQL.

However, if you did not stop after checking input data, but instead *created new piece of data* based on input, you can definitely say what this data of yours is and what it isn’t. In this case, it is definitely an integer value and nothing else. (While `is_numeric` also works for float values, did you know that? Did you intend that? No?)

And just another example: if your input is a string in hexadecimal, octal or binary notation, `is_numeric` will return `TRUE`, but your database might not even support this particular notation (MySQL does not support octal, for instance), so you will not get expected results.

Answer (score 5):

I would not endorse either version.  What you *should* be using is properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.  For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE sid = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['sid']));
```

In this case the vulnerability is handled at the *database access* level and not at the *application* level.  It may not seem like a big deal, but someone could move the query outside of the `if` statement and improperly use the query (you could make the argument that someone could also rewrite a vulnerable query, but that would be less your fault).

You can also bind values with types.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, (int)$_POST['sid']);
```

Comment: `(int)` is quite useless here. yet no type actually set

Comment: I am not using a mysql database actually, I am using and oracle database 10g using oci_connect... I don't think either one would work...